# Please help with this question about sets...

Tags: combinatorics

If #$A = n$ , determine the value of $n$ for which the number of subsets of size $4$ is equal to the number of subsets of size $8$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Is this homework? Can you share your thoughts and what you have tried? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The question asks, $${n\choose 4}={n\choose 8}$$

Use the formula of $n\choose k$ to conclude the value of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. A subset is determined by its complement. What is the size of the complement of a $4$ element subset of an $n$ element set.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Fix $n$, and think about the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{0}$, $\binom{n}{1}$, $\binom{n}{2}$, and so on all the way to $\binom{n}{n}$. These give us a full row of the Pascal Triangle.

Recall that the binomial coefficients go up, and then down, with **symmetry** about $\frac{n}{2}$. Note that $4$ and $8$ are symmetrical about $6$.

Answer (score 0):

*Claim*:  The number of subsets of size $4$ is equal to the number of subsets of size $8$ for all sets of size $n$ if and only if $n \in \{0,1,2,3,12\}.$

*Proof*:  There are $\binom{n}{4}$ subsets of size $4$ and $\binom{n}{8}$ subsets of size $8$.  We thus need to identify when $$\binom{n}{4}=\binom{n}{8}.$$

Observe that $$\binom{n}{8}-\binom{n}{4}=\frac{1}{8!}n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-7)-\frac{1}{4!}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3).$$  So the question asks for the non-negative roots of this polynomial.  The polynomial factors as $$\frac{1}{40320}(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-12)(n^2-11n+70)$$ where $n^2-11n+70$ has complex roots.  The result now follows from the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

---

Comment: The previous hints would have led you to $n=12$ as a solution (due to symmetry of the binomial coefficient).  We should also highlight that $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ are also solutions (which have sensible combinatorial interpretations).  We should also check that other values of $n$ are not also solutions.